# How to remove dashed border of select box in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I get a dashed border when I select the select box in Firefox. How can I remove it? See the image.

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/Ltcs9/

```
select.register {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    text-indent: 0.01px;
    text-overflow: '';
    appearance: none;
    font-size:14px;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-top: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
    -moz-border-radius: 1px;
    border-radius: 1px;
}

select.register:focus{
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #ff00ff;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the below to your CSS, it should fix it.

```
select:-moz-focusring {
    color: transparent;
    text-shadow: 0 0 0 #000;
}
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltcs9/3/)

Comment: @wumm: Yup mate, some browser specific implementations :(

Comment: This won't work when building a reusable component - you can't know the text colour there. It has to be inherited, and because you're setting `color`, the `currentColor` property can't be used.

Comment: @Thany Sorry but why should we know the text color? The code just sets the color of the focus ring to transparent and nullifies the text shadow (effectively). The color of the text would/should have no impact here. Can you create a fiddle demo for your problematic scenario?

Comment: @Harry, the code above resets the text colour with a faux shadow, and hardcodes it to #000. I don't want black text, I want text in the appropriate text colour. If I want to make this a reusable component, I can't blindly assume black text everywhere - I have to know the colour that was actually used somehow.

Comment: @Thany I guess you need to read the answer slowly and properly. It resets the color and shadow of a Mozilla specific style element and not your actual select box.

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
button::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="file"] > input[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: none;
}
```

You have to use this pseudo selector `::-moz-focus-inner` because this border is Firefoxs "inner focus style".

(Code: http://snipplr.com/view/16931)

Comment: how to style a select box? I cant make it work? I posted my code.

Comment: @Pavel: Yes, this trick works for buttons and other elements. But for `select` it seems to be different. Check my answer and see if it works for you.